# Using Conditional Statement within a css class (Rails/View)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

In Rails/Haml

I know this works

```
%i.class{:class => (name ? "arrow-up" : "arrow-down")}
```

I also know that I can make a helper function

```
%i.class{:class => (getArrowClass name)}

def getArrowClass value
if value == 1
   return 'arrow-up'
elsif value == 0
  return 'arrow-down'
else
  return ''
end
end #getArrowClass
```

For some reason, whenever I do the helper way it messes up my view (tables don't stick to their places), so now my question is how can I do the if elsif else in the class using the first method.

something like that

```
%i.class{:class => (if name then "arrow-up" elsif "arrow-down" else "")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with

```
%i.class{:class => ((name == 1) ? "classup" : (name == 0) ? "classdown" : "")}
```